# Replacing value after groupby

Tags: python, regex, pandas, group-by, series

I have a data frame of a grocery store record:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Tom', 'apple1'], ['Tom', 'banana35'], ['Jeff', 'pear0']]),
               columns=['customer', 'product'])
```

| customer | product |
| -------- | --------|
| Tom| apple1|
| Tom| banana35|
|Jeff| pear0|
I want to get all the products that a customer ever bought, so I used

```
product_by_customer = df.groupby('customer')['product'].unique()
product_by_customer
```

| customer |  |
| --- | --- |
| Jeff | [pear0] |
| Tom | [apple1, banana35] |

I want to get rid of the numbers after the product name. I tried

```
product_by_customer.str.replace('[0-9]', '')
```

but it replaced everything by NaN.

My desired output is
|customer||
|--------|--------|
|Jeff|pear|
|Tom|apple, banana|

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in the product column are in type nd array. Hence the replacement isnt taking place. Try the following code.

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Tom', 'apple1'], ['Tom', 'banana35'], ['Jeff', 'pear0']]),
               columns=['customer', 'product'])
df1 = df.groupby(["customer"])["product"].unique().reset_index()
df1["product"] = df1["product"].apply(lambda x: [re.sub("\d","", v ) for v in x])


df1
Out[52]: 
  customer          product
0     Jeff           [pear]
1      Tom  [apple, banana]
```

What we are doing is using the lambda function we will access each of the array value and then replace the digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can first replace and then aggregate:

```
product_by_customer = df["product"].str.replace('[0-9]', '')
    .groupby(df['customer']).unique()

print(product_by_customer)

customer
Jeff             [pear]
Tom     [apple, banana]
Name: product, dtype: object
```

Or aggregate with remove numeric:

```
import re

f = lambda x: [re.sub("[0-9]", "", v) for v in x.unique()]
product_by_customer = df.groupby('customer')['product'].agg(f)

print(product_by_customer)

customer
Jeff             [pear]
Tom     [apple, banana]
Name: product, dtype: object
```

Similar idea is remove possible duplicates by `dict.fromkeys` trick:

```
f = lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x.str.replace('[0-9]', '', regex=True)))
product_by_customer = df.groupby('customer')['product'].agg(f)

print (product_by_customer)

customer
Jeff             [pear]
Tom     [apple, banana]
Name: product, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Tom', 'apple1'], ['Tom', 'banana35'], ['Jeff', 'pear0']]),
               columns=['customer', 'product'])
df1 = df.copy()
df1["product"] = df1["product"].str.replace('[0-9]', '')
product_by_customer = df1.groupby('customer')['product'].unique()
product_by_customer
```

out :

```
customer
Jeff             [pear]
Tom     [apple, banana]
Name: product, dtype: object
```

make copy df and how about change before groupby?